# parallel processing of columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a large csv file, around 12 gb, which has about 1200 columns.
I pull each column, and do some processing, dummy the categorical variables, standardize the numeric ones and concatenate each processed column into a final dataframe.
cols_list is a list containing all the column names in the csv.

```
for column in cols_list:
    df_column = pd.read_csv('df_sample.csv', usecols = [column],delimiter = ',')
    df_column = df_column.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)

    ######################################### DATA PROCESSING #####################################
    print('*'*10 + "\nWorking on column:  " + str(column))
    print(datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    # Check if CAT and number of unique categories <=100.
    if (((attribute_dict[column] == 'CAT') & (df_column[column].unique().size <= 100))==True):

       # Add condition to replace $ with '' to fix unit8 error
        if (('$' in str(df_column[column].unique()))==True):
            df_column[column] = df_column[column].astype('str')
            df_column[column] = df_column[column].str.replace(',', '')
            df_column[column] = df_column[column].replace({'\$':''}, regex = True)
            df_column[column] = df_column[column].replace({'\<':''}, regex = True)
            unsigned_int_list.append(column)

        df_target_attribute = pd.get_dummies(df_column[column], dummy_na=True,prefix=column)
        # Check and remove duplicate columns if any:
        df_target_attribute = df_target_attribute.loc[:,~df_target_attribute.columns.duplicated()]
        df_target_matrix = df_target_attribute.values
        df_target_values = df_target_matrix.astype(int)
        df_target_columns = df_target_attribute.columns.values

        ################################# FIX uint8 error #####################################
        # Create the target_attribute df from values and column names arrays
        df_target_attribute = pd.DataFrame(data = df_target_values,columns = df_target_columns)
        df_target_attribute.fillna(0)

        for target_column in list(df_target_attribute.columns):
            # If variance of the dummy created is zero : append it to a list and print to log file.
            if ((np.var(df_target_attribute[[target_column]])[0] != 0)==True):
                df_final[target_column] = df_target_attribute[target_column]
            else:
                zero_var_list.append(target_column)


    elif (attribute_dict[column] == 'NUM'):
        df_target_attribute = df_column
        #Let's impute with 0 for numeric variables:
        df_target_attribute.fillna(value=0,inplace=True)

        # Check for variables having zero variance and skip those if true.
        if ((np.var(df_target_attribute[[column]])[0] != 0)==True):
            df_final[column] = df_target_attribute
        else:
            zero_var_list.append(column)


    elif (attribute_dict[column] == 'TARGET'):

        df_target_attribute = df_column
        df_target_attribute.fillna(value=0,inplace=True)

        if ((np.var(df_target_attribute[[column]])[0] != 0)==True):
            df_final[column] = df_target_attribute
        else:
            zero_var_list.append(column)
```

attribute_dict is a dictionary which contains the variable name as key and its datatype as value. This is used to determine the type of processing to be done
for the column.
The number of records is about 3 million and number of columns 1200. Due to the size of the data, this process takes around 22 hours to complete and give the final
dataframe - df_final.

I am wondering, if it can be sped up using multi-processing via the below scheme:
1. Process all numeric columns at once.
2. For CAT take chunks of 40 columns into a single process, hence for 1200 columns there will be 30 processes running in parallel.
3. For Target column, since it is a single column, it can also be processed separately.
So there will be a total of 32 processes runinng in parallel.
1. 1 for all NUM columns.
2. 30 for 40 chunks of CAT variables in 1 process.
3. 1 for TARGET column.

I have never done this kind of parallel processing in python, but would like to learn how to do it, if it will be helpful in this case.

I might be completely wrong in my assumption that parallel processing will help reduce the run time, in which case kindly forgive my naive question.

I can provide some sample data to replicate, but I am not sure if I am even on the right track on this one.

Can someone kindly help me in this?